# SQL confusion while trying to retrieve 2 dates

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to query a table and have dates on 2 separates rows, the first row would be the date closest to today, and the last row would contain max date.

I came up with this :

```
SELECT           
    ID_CAND, DATE_JOUR
FROM         
    Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_JOUR_NON_DISPO nd
WHERE        
    (ID_CAND = 16246)  
    AND (DATE_JOUR = (SELECT MIN(DATE_JOUR) AS Expr1
                      FROM Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_JOUR_NON_DISPO AS ds
                      WHERE (ds.ID_CAND = nd.ID_CAND) 
                        AND (DATE_JOUR > GETDATE())) 
         OR
         DATE_JOUR = (SELECT MAX(DATE_JOUR) AS Expr1
                      FROM Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_JOUR_NON_DISPO AS ds
                      WHERE (nd.ID_CAND = ds.ID_CAND) 
                        AND (DATE_JOUR > GETDATE())))
```

And it returns only one row... but when i run the inner selects separately :

```
SELECT       
    MIN(DATE_JOUR) AS Expr1
FROM            
    Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_JOUR_NON_DISPO AS ds
WHERE        
    (ID_CAND = 16246) AND (DATE_JOUR > GETDATE())

SELECT        
    MAX(DATE_JOUR) AS Expr1
FROM
    Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_JOUR_NON_DISPO AS ds
WHERE        
    (ID_CAND = 16246) AND (DATE_JOUR > GETDATE())
```

It does return 2 different values... what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The first query you posted shouldn't even work. The column ID_CAND would be ambiguous there because there is no way to know which table it comes from. And for heaven sake if you are creating aggregate data give the columns a name that means something. Expr1 is useless.

Comment: ok let me fix that i guess

Comment: what is the result you want? If we dont know what you want, we cant know what are you doing wrong.

Comment: welll the first sentence of my question is not clear enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this can help

```
Select MinDate = min(case when DATE_JOUR >= GETDATE() then DATE_JOUR else null end)
      ,MaxDate = max(DATE_JOUR)
 From  Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_JOUR_NON_DISPO          
 Where ID_CAND = 16246
```

For Two separate rows

```
Select Expr1 = min(case when DATE_JOUR >= GETDATE() then DATE_JOUR else null end)
 From  Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_JOUR_NON_DISPO          
 Where ID_CAND = 16246
Union  All
Select Expr1 = max(DATE_JOUR)
 From  Paie.dbo.PAI_CAND_JOUR_NON_DISPO          
 Where ID_CAND = 16246
```

Comment: Nop, they are on the same row... i need them in 2 separate rows

Comment: Alls good, i accept this answer when the site allows me to... in 3 minutes, and thank you very much

Comment: @Antoine Happy to help.